# Flash-игра вконтакте

Tags: разработка-игр, flash

Доброго времени!

Сделала игру в Adobe Flash Professional на ActionScript3.
Захотела выложить ее Вконтакт, полезла смотреть руководство, а там написано, что рекомендуется использовать Flash Develop и нужно подключить класс с расширением .as3proj для взаимодействия с api. У меня все классы с расширением .as, мой флеш такого расширения не знает и я сама не знала до этого момента :)

Установила Develop - я немножко в растерянности, как в нем можно делать анимацию без временной шкалы?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это в принципе делается? Рисовать во Flash Professional, а весь код писать в Develop? А классы из девелопа смогут управлять объектами на сцене из профессионала? Чем плохи мои классы .as, нужно ли менять расширение на .as3proj? Как мне наладить диалог с Вконтактом?

Спасибо!

Comment: покажите содержимое .as3proj, возможно в нем нет ничего особенного и если переименновать в .as3 то адоби скомпилирует его.

Comment: @OlmerDale Там внутри целая куча разных файлов: Три папки - _MACOSX, bin  (внутри файл TestApp.swf) - я так понимаю, уже скомпилированный и src(внутри файлы с расширением .as).

- src/ TestApp.as

Comment: @OlmerDale То есть я могу вроде как взять скомпилированный файл из flash develop, а остальное приложение оставить в том виде, в котором оно сейчас?

Comment: @OlmerDale Кажется, я начинаю разбираться) Сразу надо было посмотреть) .as3proj - это просто совокупность всех файлов проекта в одном. Спасибо вам за подсказку)

Answer (score 1):

Файл с расширением.as3proj является совокупностью всех файлов проекта - и классов .as и скомпилированного файла .swf. Его можно спокойно разделить на составляющие и работать в любой удобной программе. Графику и анимацию можно делать в файле .fla во Flash Professional, код писать там, где удобно.

В моем случае нужно было просто взять нужные классы .as и подключить их к уже созданному проекту. Даже пример есть - TestApp.as